# libgdiplus compilation error

Tags: c, mono

When I try to compile libgdiplus, I get the following error message. I use CentOS and don't have permission to run yum to install packages. My only option is to compile it from the source.

> /usr/bin/ld: .libs/image.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `gdip_getcodecinfo_gif' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[2]: *** [libgdiplus.la] Error 1

Comment: what was your ./configure line? what version of CentOS?

Comment: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib. CentOS release 5.6 (Final)

Answer (score 1):

make `yum install libungif libungif-devel` in your distribution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -Wl,-Bsymbolic to the parameters.